# Is there a way to trace IP address from where mailgun API is called

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

We are using Mailgun for email sending with Laravel and currently facing issues regarding the email being sent daily. There are four instances of sites and unable to track from where the emails are being sent out.

So is there any way we can trace IP address from where the Mailgun API is calling?

Comment: You get sender information from the email headers and you could hide sender information (to identify your node) pro-actively in the emails sent.

Comment: You can check the headers of the email you receive, the ip will be the last `Received` line. Unfortunately, while I've found you can search for your server IPs in the Mailgun logs, it doesn't actually show it.

Comment: You can use the events webhooks: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-events.html#events

Comment: yeah, I used the events webhooks and used curl request against my email address. But same mailgun credentials are using on two different sites. How can I distinguish from where that emails are sending out. 
@DanielW.

Answer (score 1):

### Adding a custom header to mailgun emails

The best way in my opinion is to mark the mails with a custom header using `h:` option:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
    -F from='Sender Bob <sbob@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
    -F to='alice@example.com' \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!' \
    -F h:X-Sender-Reference='server3'
```

This way, you can see in the event log the `X-Sender-Reference` custom header to know which server sent the message.

Keep in mind, these headers can be viewed by thee receiver aswell so do not expose sensitive information.

Depending on your library, something like this can be used:

```
$headers = $message->getHeaders();
$headers->addTextHeader('X-Sender-Reference', 'server3');
```

See: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#sending

### Tagging a mailgun email message

There is also the option to tag a message using `o:`:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
    -F from='Sender Bob <sbob@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
    -F to='alice@example.com' \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!' \
    -F o:tag='September newsletter' \
    -F o:tag='server3'
```

The allowed tags per message are limited to **three** and the purpose are marketing aggregations I think. Technically, it is possible to use it the same way as the custom header in the example above.

Some PHP libraries might be used this way:

```
$headers = $message->getHeaders();
$headers->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Tag', 'server3');
```

See: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#tagging